# write a query to display courseid and coursename which has second highest fees

Tags: sql

i tried this code

```
select courseid,coursename
from course
where fees<(select max(fees) from course)
group by courseid,coursename;
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output by editing your question. Also don't tag multiple DBMS

Comment: @Sivaknight . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

You could just order by the `fees` and take the second record using `offset`

```
select courseid, coursename
from course
order by fees desc
limit 1 offset 1
```

Comment: ...slightly depending on how you expect to handle ties

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `dense_rank()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by fees desc) as seqnum
      from course c
     ) c
where seqnum = 2;
```

This returns the *second highest* fee, even when there are duplicates for the highest fees.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select courseid,coursename from course where 
fees in(select max(fees) from course where 
fees not in(select max(fees) from course)) order by courseid;
```